# How to filter a big chunk of text which contains no line breaks in python?

Tags: python

here is my problem : I want to filter a big chunk of text with python, but all the things I found were filtering by line, ie with "if line.startswith", and I don't think I could do that here :/.

Here is my actual code :

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/new/.json');  
print(data.json())
```

I want to fetch the content between ""title:":" and ",)".
Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire point of JSON is that the parsing is handled for you -- you can JSON object as a regular Python dictionary/list.

For example, here would be how you get all of the titles in your JSON object:

```
obj = data.json()
for child in obj['data']['children']:
    print child['data']['title']
```

You can explore the structure of a chunk of JSON by either using a JSON [pretty-printer](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) (which will format the JSON string to make it easier to understand its structure), or by just exploring the object directly within Python:

```
>>> obj = data.json()
>>> type(obj)
<type 'dict'>
>>> obj.keys()
[u'kind', u'data']
>>> print obj['kind']
u'Listing'

>>> type(obj['data'])
<type 'dict'>
>>> obj['data'].keys()
[u'modhash', u'children', u'after', u'before']

>>> type(obj['data']['children'])
<type 'list'>

# etc...
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm new to all of this so I didn't know about how JSON worked :) Now it's working as I wished, thanks again !

Comment: @Kosmoz -- No problem! If my answer helped you, then click the checkmark to the upper-right of my answer to accept it and mark your question as 'solved'. (And if the other answer helped you more then this one did, then you should accept that one instead of mine)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output of `print(data.json())` The JSON Python module makes it very easy to loop over JSON data with a for ... in ... loop.  Try it out

```
for x in data.json():
    print x
```

See what the output is.  After that, add more inner loops to loop through x, you will see how you can access each piece of JSON data.